# jQuery .show() / .hide() keeps flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, show

When I hover #triangle the #tri-overlay will show up but keeps flickering because it has an conflict with the "display: none" in the css. He keeps going from "display: none" to "display: block" which causes the flickering effect. How can I avoid this conflict?

I am using the code below.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#triangle').hover(function() {
    $('#tri-overlay').show();
  }, function() {
    $('#tri-overlay').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.slide-des {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
#triangle {
  width: 12em;
  height: 10em;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
#tri-overlay {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tri-overlay" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="slide-des">
  <div id="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] using Stack Snippets?

Comment: I'm assuming that `#tri-overlay` covers `#triangle` and therefore negates the hover event, causing it to once again be hidden, which makes the hover event occur again.  Please post your html so we can see what's happening.

Comment: A snippet is something that works.

Comment: Until the snippet shows the problem in action, in a relevant manner, then it's difficult to help.  I've deleted my answer as it turned out not to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the overlay interacting with the mouse with CSS:

```
#tri-overlay{
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

When an element appears under the mouse, some browsers will immediately say it has just left the previous element under the mouse.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Borrowed sample layout from Archer:

```js
$("#element2").hover(function() {
    $("#element2-overlay").show();
  },
  function() {
    $("#element2-overlay").hide();
});
```

```css
#element2 {
  background-color: green;
}
#element2-overlay {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
}

.example {
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.example2 {
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element2" class="example example2"></div>
<div id="element2-overlay" class="example example2"></div>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a bit vague. In what scenario does it not work?

Comment: It still keeps flickering, just the same as without the pointer-events. Still a conflict between the display none and block. As I inspect the element, you see "display" is switchting from "none" to "block" and back really fast

Comment: What browser are you using and do you have a working mockup to trial it on?

Comment: I just tried this on a practical example (from Archer, without his fix) and it works just fine. Are you sure it was applied correctly? (added example above)